# laravel 4.1 fill table with data from data base

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I'm trying to fill atable with data from my data base ive done that with laravel 4.2 but in 4.1 it won't work 
 the error is

```
Undefined variable: questions (View: C:\wamp\www\happy_Road\app\views\home\home.blade.php)
```

this is the view

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Thémathique</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($questions as $question)
        <tr>
        <td>{{ $question->theme }}</td>
        <td>{{ $question->question }}</td>

        <td >
        </td>

        </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
        </table>
        {{  $questions->links(); }}
</div>
```

this is the controller

```
public function index()
{
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            $questions = questionList::paginate(10);
            return View::make('home.home')->with('user',Auth::user());
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('login')->with('message',"Vous devez vous connecter d'abord");
        }

}
```

what is wrong with this method !! any help please ! thx :)

Comment: your not passing the `$questions` to the view you are only passing the logged user data through `user` variable try to pass `$questions` data to the view through `question` variable like: `return View::make('home.home')->with(array('user'=>Auth::user(),'questions'=>$questions);`

Answer (score 3):

Pass questions through to your view

```
return View::make('home.home')
    ->with('questions', $questions)
    ->with('user', Auth::user());
```